# Crash when joining large dataframes with pandas on a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, csv, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I work for the first time with pandas. I am on a project for which I have yearly observations over 20 years. For each year I have around one million observations, each consisting of a 1x80 vector. Thus, I currently have 20 CSV files, one for each year, composed roughly of 1 000 000 rows by 80 columns. Each of the CSV file is around 400 000 Ko.

I would like to join those files into a single one using pandas join function. Given that the datasets do not necessarily have overlapping observations and that the columns are labeled by year, I would end up with a several million rows by 1600 (80*20) columns CSV file.

Now, my problem is that my computer crashes every time I try to join these files through IPython (using a jupyter notebook), probably because it is beyond its capacity to handle the join. It has 65 GB available memory and 8 GB RAM.

The code I am using is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

z = pd.read_csv('path_to_file/Year1.csv', low_memory=False)

for year in [Year 2, Year 3, ..., Year 20]:
    y = pd.read_csv('path_to_file/'+ str(year) + '.csv', low_memory=False)
    y = set_index('observation_name')
    z = z.join(other=y, on='observation_name', how='outer')

z.to_csv('path_to_file/Name.csv')
```

No error message is displayed and the code works fine when I iterate only on two or three years. But when I start iterating over more than four years, my computer just freezes quickly so that I have to shutdown. For information, after merging the three first years the dataset is already around 1 500 000 rows and 240 columns.

Does anyone have some experience on a similar issue? How can I efficiently join these datasets? Should I use another language/a computer with more capabilities? Any advices are welcome.

Comment: I have a similar experience with pandas and read_sql_query on notebook. Notebook crashes on large db. What I did before is load db-> dataframe-> my custom class. But now I skip the dataframe step: load db (my own reader instead of pandas) -> my custom class, and things are working great. Just my own experience, may not be helpful to your case.

Comment: If you are willing to change the tool, you can try using Apache Spark. Advantage : 1. You will be writing the code in Python. 2. Spark has DataFrames. It is similar to pandas in a lot of way so learning curve will be small.

Comment: Is this problem solved? I'm having the same issue